# Passing a vector<class> myvector to an constructor and accessing it

Tags: c++, oop

Sorry if a question similar is posted about this already, but I don't know how to word this question properly.  How can I access "William" and "Shakespeare" with cout << that was passed into Author object shakespeare, which was then passed into the vector of authors which was then passed into the Book object play?

```
class Author{} //has private variables first_name and last_name and getter 
               //functions in public.

class Book{
private:
    vector<Author> author_mem;
public:
    Book(const vector<Author>& author_fn):author_mem(author_fn){}
    vector<Author> get_author_list() const {return author_mem;}
}

int main(){
    const Author shakespeare("William","Shakespeare");
    const vector<Author> authors = {shakespeare};
    const Book play(authors);
    //initiial idea was to have something like 
    //cout << play.get_author_list.at(0)

}
```

Comment: Are you asking what you need to do so that `cout << play.get_author_list().at(0);` causes `William Shakespeare` to be sent to `cout` ?

Comment: Of course, you can access William and Shakespeare at any time by using `play.get_author_list().at(0).get_first_name()` etc.  , without reference to cout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you named your accessors for your `Author` class, but let's say it's `GetFirstName` and `GetLastName`.

That should work:

```
cout << play.get_author_list().at(0).GetFirstName();
cout << play.get_author_list().at(0).GetLastName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put something along the lines of this into your Author class to overload the << operator:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Author & author)
{
    output << //this depends on how you stored the data in Author probably
    // output << author.firstname << " " author.lastname;
}
```

Then `cout << play.get_author_list().at(0)` will work.

Consider adding `Author& get_author(size_t index)` and `size_t get_author_listsize()` methods so that you don't have to expose the vector inside Book. No point handing around private data, and you may want to replace the container one day.

Or even more fun:

```
typedef vector<Author>::iterator AuthorIterator;
```

and then

```
AuthorIterator getAuthorBegin()
{
    return author_mem.begin();
}
AuthorIterator getAuthorEnd()
{
    return author_mem.end();
}
```

Comment: "Consider adding a `Author& get_author(size_t index)` method": but then he should also add a `get_author_count()` method.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57 Good call. Even better is to pass around a vector::iterator hidden behind an alias like `typedef AuthorIterator vector::iterator`. 'course then you need begin and end functions.